# Tensorflow model.fit stuck at first epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently trying to build a Tensorflow CNN Model on FashionMNIST dataset.

Environment:
Tensorflow Version: 2.3.0
CUDA Toolkit 10.1
cuDNN v7.6
python 3.8.3

Script:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
print("Tensorflow Version:", tf.__version__)

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
#### Import the Fashion MNIST dataset
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images1 = train_images[:,:,:,np.newaxis]
test_images1 = test_images[:,:,:,np.newaxis]
##Scale these values to a range of 0 to 1 before feeding them to the neural network model
### Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

##Create the convolutional base
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.summary()
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

###Train the model
##Feed the model
history = model.fit(train_images1, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images1, test_labels))
```

At `model.fit`, it showed a `Epoch 1/10` without any progress bar for a long time without showing any error. On top of this, I also found that defining model takes quite a long time than expected; about 2 minutes.

Comment: I believe you have a hardware issue because it runs fine on my machine, I commented out the `__future__` import since you dont use it

Comment: I'm not sure if it was a driver issue, but gonna test it out. (Link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36072#issuecomment-664672783)

Comment: yes it could be drivers as well, but it's not a coding issue

Answer (score 0):

when you use model.fit(), the program load the data, which takes lots of time.

try running the same code on colab. your code is fine.